# Javascript Confirmation for CheckBox on Unchecked Click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a checkbox that auto post when changed.

The auto post works fine for both (checked and unchecked), but I want to popup a dialog box to confirm before each event takes place.

So far the popup box works when the checkbox is checked.

But it does not popup a confirmation dialog box, when the checkbox is unchecked.

**Question:** How do I popup a dialog box for the uncheck event using client side code (only)

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CurrentCheckBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked='<%# Bind("BDValue") %>' OnCheckedChanged="SharedFunctionForThisCheckBox_CheckedChanged" onclick="checkBoxConfirmClick(this);" />


<script type="text/javascript">        
    function checkBoxConfirmClick(elementRef) {
        if (elementRef.checked) {
            if (window.confirm('Are you sure?') == false)
                elementRef.checked = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current method works then you can simplify to

```
function checkBoxConfirmClick(elementRef) {
    if (!window.confirm('Are you sure?')) { // if not sure
        elementRef.checked = !elementRef.checked; // toggle back
    }
}
```

However, it would really be best to pass the event through into the handler instead (i.e. as `e`) and then you could do

```
function checkBoxConfirmClick(e) {
    if (!window.confirm('Are you sure?')) { // if not sure
        e.preventDefault(); // kill the click
    }
}
```

You may also want to `e.stopPropagation()` if you have other handlers attached higher up that you don't want this event to reach.

- [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- [`event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)